# Using previous row to calculate sum of current row

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a python issue which I can't seem to figure out. The following dataframe illustrates persons who are spending money in given years and months:

| ID | Year | Month | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 134 | 2020 | 11 | -199 |
| 134 | 2020 | 12 | -50 |
| 134 | 2021 | 1 | 40 |
| 135 | 2020 | 11 | -365 |
| 135 | 2020 | 12 | -23 |
| 135 | 2021 | 1 | 400 |

However, I want to add a new column that sums these expenses each month.

**Example**: A person spends 50 euro's in the 1st month and 100 in the 2nd. This will amount to 150 euro's spent in total in month 2. I want to illustrate this spending behaviour in the new column with the assumption that everyone has 100 euro's as starting capital. (This is why In the example below, a person spends 200 but the new column shows -100.

Here is the column that I would like:

| ID | Year | Month | Amount | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 134 | 2020 | 11 | -200 | -100 |
| 134 | 2020 | 12 | -50 | -150 |
| 134 | 2021 | 1 | 40 | -110 |
| 135 | 2020 | 11 | -365 | -265 |
| 135 | 2020 | 12 | -23 | -288 |
| 135 | 2021 | 1 | 400 | 112 |

Here is the code to recreate the first dataframe:

```
data = {'ID': ['134', '134','134','135','135','135',], 'Year': [2020, 2020, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2021,], 'Month': [11, 12, 1, 11, 12, 1], 'Amount': [-199, -50, 40, -365, -23, 400]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I've tried cumsum() and .rolling but can't figure it out.
Hopefully I've given enough info and otherwise I'll be happy to supply some more

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumsum() + 100`:

```
df["NewColumn"] = df.groupby(["ID"])["Amount"].cumsum()+100
```

**Output:**

```
    ID  Year        Month   Amount  NewColumn
0   134     2020    11      -199    -99
1   134     2020    12      -50     -149
2   134     2021    1       40      -109
3   135     2020    11      -365    -265
4   135     2020    12      -23     -288
5   135     2021    1       400     112
```

PS: there is a small difference to your expected output, as you started with `-200`, but in the data it was `-199` :-)

Comment: Sweet dude. And as far as the -199 goes, you're right. It's ll about the details